# How do you make cloud build project history publicly readable?

Tags: google-cloud-build

I have [google cloud build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/) set up, and I'd like t away to make the builds publicly visible, to use in an open source project, a bit like how TravisCI and CircleCI offer - see an example below:

https://travis-ci.org/wagtail/Willow/pull_requests

Is this possible?

Can you make it possible to inspect a build to a non-signed in user?

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to use [Google Identity and Access Management](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview) to grant the [Cloud Build Viewer role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#cloud-build-roles) to [allUsers](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview#allusers). **However**, this cannot be done at the moment.
The idea is to give the `cloudbuild.builds.get` and `cloudbuild.builds.list` permissions to everyone on the internet, which would allow them to call those Cloud Build API methods that require these permissions. You can grant roles to Google Accounts or Groups, Service accounts or G Suite domains, but not to everyone.

You can find detailed instructions to grant roles through the GCP console in the Cloud Build [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/configure-access-control#managing_iam_roles_via_the).

Comment: Can you give more detail on how to do this. I am getting "Members of type allUsers and allAuthenticatedUsers cannot be added to this resource".

Comment: I've been testing, and indeed it is not possible, neither with the console or API calls. Security policies regarding the identities allUsers and allAuthenticatedUsers have been made more restrictive. I'll change my answer.